# How to convert float to percentage in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to turn a floating point number (0.02) into a percentage(2%). What is they syntax in ruby?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: How to print a decimal as a percent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455813/rails-how-to-print-a-decimal-as-a-percent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a float to a percentage, multiply the float by 100. If you need to output it with the % sign, use string interpolation inside a string.

Example:

```
percentage_value  = 0.02 * 100
puts "#{percentage_value}%"
```

> 2.0%

{edited}

Comment: This actually prints `2.0%`